# Unable send a message with stompclient

Tags: python-2.7, activemq-classic, stomp

Iam trying to send a message to activemq using pythons stompclient.
https://bitbucket.org/hozn/stompclient/wiki/User%20Documentation
If there is a better library for this Im open to suggestions.
If i change to ip or port it will fail to connect so im assuming that the connection is working. There are no errors when I run this code its just that I see no messages on the queue. I think the destination path is possibly where it is failing the PhysicalName of the activemq queue is in this pattern 'abc.queue_name'.
I've tried the following destinations

```
/queue/abc/queue_name
/queue/abc.queue_name
abc.queue_name
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
from stompclient import PublishClient
client = PublishClient('IP', 53680)

response = client.connect('defaultPassword', 'defaultUser')
reponse1 = client.send('/queue/abc/queue_name', 'bla')
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the webconsole to see if your Queue was created by the send?

You should also try adding a request id onto the send and waiting for a response, this will ensure that the broker has enough time to get the sent data before you client code disconnects.

You might also want to check the Broker logs to see if any errors are logged or any security warnings in case the user doesn't have publish rights.

Comment: Thanks for your repy. I can see the queue via the webconsole and can send messages to the queue via the webconsole. The activemq logs show this warning 2014-05-09 14:06:34,928 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IP:PORT failed: java.io.IOException: Java heap space | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ NIO Worker 44146

Comment: I would guess that either you've exhausted resources on the machine or you've attempted to connect a STOMP client to the OpenWire port on the broker.

Comment: resources are fine as I can send messages via the webconsole how do I know if this is the case with the OpenWire port

Answer (score 0):

Added this property to the activemq.xml file and im now seeing messages on the queue via the web console.

```
<transportConnector name="stomp"  uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613"/>
```